# Magento: move the “My Cart” box from the right column to the left

Tags: php, magento

I am tiring to move “My Cart” box from the right column to the left and followed the instruction from http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts. I change `<reference name="right"> to <reference name="left">` in checkout.xml . After that, the “My Cart” disappear from right, but it doesn't display in left. I don't understand what's the wrong.  Please help me.

Comment: Make sure about your theme package directory and try it after clear all cache.

Answer (score 0):

Saifur,first clear cache  from  `/magentodic/delete var/cache folder`
if it is not working  then check `checkout.xml`

```
 <default>

        ...
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

this syntax should be `in  <default></default> tag in checkout.xml`

Comment: I deleted the cache folder and cache is disabled from admin. And the reference in inside default tag. but stil it does not work

Comment: Please check var/system.log and exception.log

Comment: There is no ystem.log and exception.log file under var folder

Comment: Enable log from admin>system>configuration>Developer, from here enable log.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set page template to 2 columns left:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Magento Admin panel and there set in CMS/Pages which page you want to 3 columns layout. Probably it will be Home Page. Make sure you have correct Store View.